# RAW SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

1. Is there any way to instruct sqlmap to perform normal injections without escaping and commenting? For example, it's confirmed that `id=1111+or+(INJECTION_HERE)=1--+` is valid, so can I instruct sqlmap to use that as an injection point and extract the data?
2. If `id=(pg_sleep(10))` would result in a sleep, is there any tool or sqlmap to perform the injection without injecting a single quote where it would just immediately automate all possible queries to retrieve data
3. Is it possible to specify a HTTP timeout as the true condition?

**Update:**

Using `--time-sec` even though, I've checked it in BurpSuite, a HTTP Timeout Occurs, but SQLMAP still does not detect a valid Injection. The reason might be because, `--time-sec` is used for Time-Based Injection, whereas the HTTP Timeout occurs when a valid SQL Query is submitted and the server is takes a long time to provide a response (Due to huge amount of data).

HTTP Request (request1.txt)

```
POST /bin/<redacted>/RedactedServlet HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 57
Host: example.com
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
DNT: 1
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Origin: https://example.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://example.com/example.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-MY,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<REDACTED>
Connection: close

id=111*
```

SQLMap Command: `sqlmap -r request1.txt --proxy=http://127.0.0.1:4442  --force-ssl --time-sec=3 --suffix=" or 1=1-- "`

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I skip encoding?

As [the documentation](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage) clearly states, the flag `--skip-urlencode` can be used to skip URL encoding.

#### How can I prevent sqlmap from injecting a single quote?

It will automatically try as many possible injection formats as it can - including direct WHERE-clause or direct sub-SELECT injection. This should be the default behavior.

#### Is it possible to specify a HTTP timeout as true condition?

The documentation states:

> It is possible to set the seconds to delay the response when testing for time-based blind SQL injection, by providing the `--time-sec` option followed by an integer. By default it's value is set to 5 seconds.

This means that by default, if a response takes longer than 5 seconds, sqlmap considers the condition to be "true". A HTTP timeout is nothing else than your client saying that the server took too long to respond. Feel free to set the value to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Updated the question regarding `--time-sec`, it still did'nt work even though a HTTP Timeout Occurs in BurpSuite. The reason might be because, `--time-sec` is used for Time-Based Injection, whereas the HTTP Timeout occurs when a valid SQL Query is submitted and the server is takes a long time to provide a response (Due to huge amount of data).

Comment: If you are running sqlmap through Burp, then try increasing Burp's timeout limit. A timeout is a client-side event, where the client says "The server is taking too long." Documentation on how to do that can be found [here](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/options/connections)

Comment: Yeah, that's possible, but then again, i guess there's no way to indicate to sqlmap that says HTTP Timeout is a TRUE condition? Because, SQLMap did use the correct Injection query, but then, because of the page requiring a LONG time to respond, the timeout is reached, i would prefer if i don't have to change any BurpSuite or SQLMap settings, all i need is just to indicate to sqlmap that says HTTP Timeout == True.

Comment: Why are you not using `--string=` to check for the burp timeout page? That should be equivalent

Comment: So --string=""? I'll try that the next time i have the chance, since the engagement ended, thanks!